# What happens if a functor being executed by a thread is moved?

Tags: c++, stl, thread-safety, functor

Say I have a functor F like

```
struct F
{
    // <some member variables go here>
    void operator()() { while(true) /*do stuff affecting the state*/; }
};
```

If I create a vector of Fs

```
std::vector<F> functorVec(10);
```

and then start a bunch of threads with these functors

```
for (int i = 0; i < functorVec.size(); ++i)
{
    boost::thread(functorVec[i]); 
}
```

and now I do some stuff to my vector like

```
functorVec.push_back(F());
```

If the vector expands and copies its contents to a new location, does this cause undefined behavior in the threads? Or will they simply crash?

It seems as though their state has moved, possibly in the middle of some operation they were doing on it. In actuality the object doing the work is copied then deleted, right? Since the move is asynchronous to the execution of the threads so it seems like it would be bad news.

I ask because I want to be able to keep a collection of objects each running their own thread. These objects represent modules attached to a system. I would like to be able to add  and detach modules on the fly. If storing objects in a collection is not a good idea, what is the alternative? Do I have to allocate them on the heap and store pointers in my collections?

If this is not a problem at all, could you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html):

> **Launching threads**
>
> A new thread is launched by passing an object of a callable type that
>   can be invoked with no parameters to the constructor. The object is
>   then **copied** into internal storage, and invoked on the newly-created
>   thread of execution. If the object must not (or cannot) be copied,
>   then boost::ref can be used to pass in a reference to the function
>   object. In this case, the user of Boost.Thread must ensure that the
>   referred-to object outlives the newly-created thread of execution.

Since thread arguments are copied, moving the vector after all the threads are started would not be a problem.

Comment: So if I want to interact with the callable object during its execution I need to pass it with boost::ref. What is a safe way to store the callable object during its execution then? Do I have to allocate it on the heap and store a pointer if I want to use a collection?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of boost::thread accepts the functor by value:

```
template <class F> explicit thread(F f);
```

That means it copies the functor you provided, so id doesn't refer the object you have in your vector of functors. Therefore, there should be no impact.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [boost::thread documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor), you don't need to store the functor at all. The callable object will be copied upon construction and the original you supplied will never be referenced again.